# Is this approach to website design adequate or am i making a mistake?

Tags: website-design

I'm not conversant with this topic, therefore i watched [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_QXkBHy8yVo085n2_3T9S0h8vfW-ksVp) about a one-page dynamic PHP website (quite educational in my opinion) in which the creator designed the following pages.
[image]

For each and every ADD, DELETE  and EDIT page, there are two additional files to create, making 2 per page. In other words, (1*2)*3 = 6 subpages or (3*3) = 9 pages if we consider ADD, DELETE and EDIT as well.

Now that i'm considering designing a similar website as part of my college thesis, i repeated the process, leaving me with this.

[image]

By way of counting, we have:

- 7 ADD pages (7*3 = 21).
- 7 DELETE pages (7*3 = 21).
- 3 UPDATE pages (3*3 = 9).

Making a total of 51 pages to cover all of ADD, DELETE and UPDATE in the design. In my opinion, this is a considerable amount of pages to design, even if most of them are sufficiently generic in their structure that i could copy and paste them with minimal modifications required most of the time.

Perhaps i'm focusing too much on the number to see the bigger picture, which brings me to you. Are there alternatives to this scenario or should i devote myself to creating each page? Perhaps i made a mistake?

Comment: You generally only need 1 "add", "delete" or "update" script/page, then you can pass a variable to the PHP script to handle which "category" is being added/deleted/updated. I can see a possibility for that entire wireframe to be built with a *total* of only 4 pages (depending upon layouts). -- This is a question better suited to http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think this is a graphic design question.  I wonder if Stackoverflow might be better, or perhaps even User Experience Stack Exchange.

Comment: Its an UX question imho.

Comment: Interesting question but not UX—maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/